# Combine two array and order this new array by date

Tags: php, arrays

. I have two array

First One

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2012-01-10
                [result] => 65
                [name] => Les océans
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2012-01-11
                [result] => 75
                [name] => Les mers
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2012-01-13
                [result] => 66
                [name] => Les continents
                [type] => Scores
            )

    )
```

The second

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date_end] => 2012-01-12
            [result] => 60
            [name] => Step#1
            [type] => Summary
        )

)
```

And I want this for my final result

```
 Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2012-01-10
                    [result] => 65
                    [name] => Les océans
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2012-01-11
                    [result] => 75
                    [name] => Les mers
                )

             [2] => Array
            (
                [date_end] => 2012-01-12
                [result] => 60
                [name] => Step#1
                [type] => Summary
            )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2012-01-13
                    [result] => 66
                    [name] => Les continents
                    [type] => Scores
                )

        )
```

So .... I need to combine my first array with the second  and I want to order this new array   by date !... Can someone can help me on hint me for doing this ?  Thx !

Comment: You need to make `JOIN` when you select this from DB

Comment: @dfsq You're assuming there is a database.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is. And if so OP has chosen wrong approach.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Would be better to show your code here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge) and [usort](http://php.net/usort) is your friend.

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    $ad = strtotime($a['date']);
    $bd = strtotime($b['date']);
    return ($ad-$bd);
}
$arr = array_merge($array1, $array2);
usort($arr, 'cmp');
```

Comment: as a side note I really suggest reading the usort php documentation (the answer links to it), it makes things a lot easier to understand. Especially the seemingly mysterious return($ad-$db) and usort($arr, 'cmp');

Comment: I asked a question related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243553/how-does-this-usort-cmp-function-actually-work

May be you could help?

Comment: May be I saw your question too late. Fortunately there is a good answer to your question already.

Answer (score 3):

Use array_merge() to combine the arrays, and then use sort to sort() to sort them, very simple. Would you like an example?

This should sort it for you:

```
function dateSort($a,$b){
    $dateA = strtotime($a['date']);
    $dateB = strtotime($b['date']);
    return ($dateA-$dateB);
}

$arrayOne = array(
    array(
        'date'      => '2012-01-10',
        'result '   => 65,
        'name'      => 'Les oc&eacute;ans'
    ),
    array(
        'date'      => '2012-01-11',
        'result '   => 75,
        'name'      => 'Les mers'
    ),
    array(
        'date'      => '2012-01-13',
        'result '   => 66,
        'name'      => 'Les continents',
        'type'      => 'Scores'
    )
);

$arrayTwo = array(
    array(
        'date'      => '2012-01-12',
        'result '   => 60,
        'name'      => 'Step#1',
        'type'      => 'Summary'
    )
);

// Merge the arrays
$combinedArray = array_merge($arrayOne,$arrayTwo);

// Sort the array using the call back function
usort($combinedArray, 'dateSort');
```

Comment: Yes please , that will be appreciated

Comment: Will get back to you in a minute

Comment: Do you need to store the date as a date, or can you simply use a timestamp? You can then convert the timestamp to a date if needed. I only ask because it makes it slightly easier to sort.

Comment: I need to use YYYY/MM/DD  format, I already have an timestamp field in the same table ,   but is not usefull for this part.

Answer (score 1):

`array_merge` your arrays and then use the following code as an example of how you can sort it.

```
function sortDate($val1, $val2)
{
    if ($val1['date'] == $val2['date']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return (strtotime($val1['date']) < strtotime($val2['date'])) ? -1 : 1;
}

$array = array(
    array('date' => '2012-01-10'),
    array('date' => '2011-01-10'),
    array('date' => '2012-01-01')
);

usort($array, "sortDate");
print_r($array);
```